# facebook JS SDK batch request for custom actions

Tags: facebook, api, object, batch-file, facebook-opengraph

I have written the following method to check if a user has submitted any of the 3 custom  open graph actions on a webpage:

```
function checkOpenGraphHistory()
{
    var actionList = new Array($('#fb1').attr("data-action"), $('#fb2').attr("data-action"), $('#fb3').attr("data-action"));
    var nameList = new Array($('#fb1').attr("data-name"), $('#fb2').attr("data-name"), $('#fb3').attr("data-name"));
    var idList = new Array('#fb1', '#fb2','#fb3');
    var i = 0;

    while(i < actionList.length)
    {
    FB.api('me/' + actionList[i] + '/?fields=id&object=' + location.href,
       function (checkResponse)
       {
           --i; //the callbacks seem to be added to a queue instead of being processed per api request. Without this line, i always = actionList.length.
           if (!checkResponse)
           {
               console.log('Check: Empty response checking: ' + checkResponse.error.message);
           }
           else if (checkResponse.error)
           {
               console.log('Check: ERROR checking: ' + checkResponse.error.message);
           }
           else if (checkResponse.data.length < 1)
           {
               console.log('Check: User has not ' + nameList[i] + ' this item before.');
           }
           else
           {
               console.log('Check: User ' + nameList[i] + 'ed item before, ID: ' + checkResponse.data[0].id + " actionList.length: " + actionList.length + "and i is: " + i);
           }
       }  );
       i++;
    }
}
```

This performs 3 HTTP requests and the accuracy of the results this returns isn't 100%. So, I either want to turn this into a batch request, FQL request or I want to query the webpage/object via the API and return all actions (currently 3 custom actions, one a built-in action and 2 are custom actions) the current user performed on this webpage/object.

Something like this would be fine:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/{appNameSpace}:{action}/{object}

However I want to check more than one action, I want to check at least 3 actions on one object for now, maybe more actions in the future.

I tried to use the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) with the parameter:

```
me/?batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/myNamespace:myAction/", "object":"objectURL"}]
```

and

```
me/?batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/myNamespace:myAction/", "body":"url=objectURL"}]
```

However this returns more than one instance of the custom action on this specific object/url, not just the information about that specific action on that specific object. The user can only perform the unique action once per object (one to one relationship) but can perform all three actions once, so I only want to return one result per action, specifically whether or not the user performed the specified action on the specified object.